# How to Fix inaccuracy of Google Analytics data? Goals are not getting recorded perfectly in Magento

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

Case: It's an e-commerce website running on the magneto. 
Condition: I've installed google analytics code UA- on the website in all the pages of it.

Issue: The Goals those who are getting recorded is very less as compare to actual data that is recorded in Magento dashboard.

For the last month data the goals in Analytics recorded 81 sales where as the actual sales was 421 as per Magento which is the accurate figure.

How: How to fix this issue so, that we can get the accurate data in Google analytics.

So, that I can see

1. How many users who viewed the product but, didn't added that to the cart / take any actions or bought the product.
2. How many users added the product but, didn't bought it.
3. How many users actually bought the product.
4. The buyers came from which medium/source/campaign
5. Which campaign give us the maximum result and which one is the waste
6. Which source is bringing us the maximum conversions.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't explain the exact issue in terms of data being not accurate.

Generally, a system like Magento got some issue if you just enable eCommerce tracking and can be fixed by manual configuration, i am not sure if that is the case.

Now, with regards to Goals, check if the Goal is created correctly.

Go to: GA >> Admin >> View >> Goals >> Click on the Goal you have created

Click on Edit under Goal Details and then you may like to see the value if you verify.

Note: The key to data inconsistency may be caused by required Yes / No value. Setup based on your need.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry for the bad question. I'll fix it. 

Issue: The Data is not accurate. 
The Traffic record for the e-commerce is 9000+ 

it recorded 81 final conversions in Google analytics. But, the actual conversions were 421 recorded in Magento. So, how to fix this issue. Because I've installed the GA which is defined in Google documentation like add the UA-code.

Now, How to make the data more accurate so, that I can get greater glimpse on 
how many people added the product into cart
How many of them just viewed the product 
and Which source brings how many conversions.

Comment: Do this and it should fix it.

Comment: 1.) Create goals correctly, its URL-based so it should work fine at least. 2) With regards to eCommerce tracking, if you have just enabled eCommerce tracking in GA then depending on Magento setup it may not record all conversion. And to ensure it record all orders, try and do manual/custom eCommerce setup and it should fix the issue. It's not hard, you will get ready made JS and you need to place in order confirmation page and ensure you assign all required values like: Order ID, Product Info, Total, Tax etc. Also, you can troubleshoot this every effectively.

Comment: Also, make sure after payment, all goes to the order confirmation page.